# Recursive List: Everything calling destructor

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to make a recursive linked list. It looks a bit like this:

```
class List  
{   int cur; //For now 
    List* nxt;

public:
    List()
        {cur = nullptr; nxt = nullptr;}
    ~List()
        {std::cout << "Destroyed\n";}

...
```

Now I have a function cons,

```
List cons(const int &a)
{   if(cur == nullptr)
    {   cur = new int;
        *cur = a;
    }
    else
    {   List* x = new List;
        x->cur = new int;
        *(x->cur) = *cur;
        x->nxt = nxt;
        *cur = a;
        nxt = x;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

And an operator,

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const List &b)
{   out << "Output\n";
    return out;
}
```

I'm using this code in main to drive it:

```
int main()
{   List a;
    std::cout << "Cons\n";
    a.cons(3);
    std::cout << "Cons\n";
    a.cons(2);
    std::cout << "Cons\n";
    a.cons(1);
    std::cout << a;
}
```

This, when ran, results in:

```
Cons
Destroyed
Cons
Destroyed
Cons
Destroyed
Out
Destroyed
Destroyed
```

My questions are,
a, why is it calling a destructor inside a member function,
b, why is it calling a destructor on a const reference,
and c, how the hell do destructors work and how do I stop mine from constantly killing itself?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `List cons(const int &a)` returns a copy of `*this`. This results in a bunch of temporary `List` objects.

The destructor calls you are seeing are for the copies returned from each call to `cons`.

Tip: Use `List& cons(int a)` instead.

Comment: Ahh. Wonderful, thanks. I guess a follow up would be, I'm planning on writing a body() or tail() function which returns *nxt for use with recursion... Would the approach to that also be List&? For example, I'm imagining I'll eventually implement the << operator as {out << a.head(); out << a.tail()}. When the call to a.tail() goes out of scope, will that delete the rest of the List?

Comment: If `head()` and `tail()` return a reference then no, no destructors will be called and nothing will be deleted (as is expected from calling head/tail).